# SSD -- Special settings for SSD as secondary drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, trim

I recently purchased an Intel SSD (X25-V 40GB) and I want to add it to my PC as a secondary drive (not the boot/system drive) so I can install specific software to it. Now, do I need to do anything special to ensure long life and peak performance with this as a secondary drive? I have Windows 7 Pro. by the way. All the literature I can find covers the use of a SSD as a boot/system drive under Windows 7, but I don't want to run it like that (I have my reasons). I'm wondering if things like TRIM still work if you don't use the SSD as the boot/system drive. If TRIM and the like still works, do I have to do anything special in order to enable it for my particular setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Here are some quotes from [an (older) Microsoft presentation on SSDs](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/E/6/5E66B27B-988B-4F50-AF3A-C2FF1E62180F/COR-T558_WH08.pptx)

It mentions that if the SSD follows **SATA guidelines**, then Windows 7 is able to **recognize it** and **adjust accordingly**. Regardless of being the primary or secondary drive.

> SSD can identify itself differently
>   from HDD in ATA as defined by ATA8-ACS
>   Identify Word 217:  Nominal media
>   rotation rate
>
> Reporting non-rotating media will
>   allow Windows 7to set Defrag off as
>   default; improving device endurance by
>   reducing writes
>
> From the Windows 7 Storage Logo
>   Proposal:
>
> - If “Trim” algorithm is applied, the “Trim” implementation must comply with
>     ATA8-ACS2 proposal e07154r6 (Data Set
>     Management Commands Proposal for
>     ATA8-ACS2) section 5.3 and section
>     6.2. The completion time of Trim command should be less or equal to
>     20ms
> - SATA-IO certification is required for Solid State Drive (SSD) connected
>     through SATA interface. More
>     information on SATA-IO testing will be
>     available on the [SATA-IO Web site](http://www.sata-io.org/testing.asp)

Comment: First off, thanks for responding. TRIM is a firmware improvement, though it only works when the OS is capable of passing "TRIM" commands to the SSD. Only Win7 can do this at the moment. There is however no discussion about TRIM for secondary SSD implementations. When Win7 detects a SSD as the primary drive, it's supposed to disable ReadyBoost, Superfetch, defrag, indexing, etc., and enable TRIM commands. Does this also happen if you're using the SSD as a non-system drive? This covers Win7 and TRIM: http://www.tweaktown.com/guides/3116/tweaktown_s_solid_state_drive_optimization_guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the update. The presentation was a good read. So, if I understand everything correctly, because the SSD identifies itself as non-rotating media, per the ATA spec, Win7 should be smart enough to enable the TRIM commands and disable the appropriate Windows utilities for just that particular drive? I did not however read where it explicitly states primary/secondary drive status is inconsequential, though I do see how one could come to that conclusion after reading through the presentation. I will continue to search for more info on this. Thanks again for looking into this too.

Comment: If it would make a difference, it would be all over the internet with people complaining about it ;-) Plus given that they recently added TRIM support for RAID setups, I assume there aren't any limitations to the usage (if supported)

Comment: Hello again. You make some excellent points. I just updated my ICH drivers and I'm going to install the drive now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, now just hope I'm right and that your system will rock ;-) If you have any other questions feel free to ask them!

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with TRIM on second SSD. All you need to do is to set your second SSD as `active`.

Go to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools Computer Management`. Click on `Disk Management`. Find your second SSD and right click on it and make it `Active`. Reboot windows.

Test with `trimcheck-0.7`. TRIM should work. It worked for me. I have Primary SSD OCZ and secondary KingFast.